# Error "The object store currently does not support blob values" when trying to store file in indexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm trying to make a storage in javascript using IndexedDB to store blobs.
Here is my code

```
var Storage = (function () {
    function Storage(callback) {
        var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.OIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB, IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.OIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction, dbVersion = 1.0;

        this.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

        var request = indexedDB.open('files', dbVersion);
        var self = this;

        request.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log("Error creating/accessing IndexedDB database");
        };

        request.onsuccess = function (e) {
            console.log("Success creating/accessing IndexedDB database");
            self.db = request.result;

            self.db.onerror = function (event) {
                console.log("Error creating/accessing IndexedDB database");
            };

            // Interim solution for Google Chrome to create an objectStore. Will be deprecated
            if (self.db.setVersion) {
                if (self.db.version != dbVersion) {
                    var setVersion = self.db.setVersion(dbVersion);
                    setVersion.onsuccess = function () {
                        self.createObjectStore(self.db);
                        callback();
                    };
                } else {
                    callback();
                }
            } else {
                callback();
            }
        };

        // For future use. Currently only in latest Firefox versions
        request.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
            self.createObjectStore(e.target.result);
        };
    }
    Storage.prototype.createObjectStore = function (db) {
        console.log('Creating objectStore');
        db.createObjectStore('files');
    };

    Storage.prototype.putFile = function (fileName, blob) {
        console.log('Putting file in IndexedDB');
        var transaction = this.db.transaction(['files'], 'readwrite');
        var put = transaction.objectStore('files').put(blob, fileName);
    };

    return Storage;
})();
```

I'm using it like that :

```
var storage = new Storage(function () {
    var blob = new Blob(['FooBar']);
    storage.putFile('test', blob);
});
```

On Chrome i get :

```
DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': The object store currently does not support blob values.
```

On Firefox i get :

```
[Exception... "Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements."  code: "0" nsresult: "0x80660005 (DataError)"  location: "<unknown>"]
```

I don't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find the answer to my question. Well, I did find somthing to resolve the problem : "how to store files permanently in Firefox ?"

I found a FileSystem fallback : https://github.com/ebidel/idb.filesystem.js

It works well.