# Why is chrome showing error " The object store currently does not support blob values" when trying to store file in IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, indexeddb

I am new to Javascript and IndexedDB. Currently I am writing code for a simple utility which uploads file(s) and stores them in IndexedDB. Then user has the option of either seeing the file names or the contents of the file, which is directly read from stored files in IndexedDB.

Following is my javascript code-

```
var db;
var display="";

function indexedDOok(){
return "indexedDB" in window;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

if(!indexedDOok())
    return;

var openRequest = indexedDB.open("fileIndex", 1);

openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(e){
    var thisDB = e.target.result;

    if(!thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains("docs")){
        thisDB.createObjectStore("docs", {autoIncrement:true});
        console.log("Database upgrading....");
    }
};

openRequest.onsuccess = function(e){
   db = e.target.result;
   console.log("Database created");
   document.querySelector("#fileSelector").addEventListener("change",    handleFileSelection, false);
   document.querySelector("#displayButton").addEventListener("click", displayContent,                                              false);
   document.querySelector("#getButton").addEventListener("click", getFiles, false);
};

openRequest.onerror = function(e){
    console.log(e.target.result);
};
}, false);

function handleFileSelection(e){
    console.log("Inside file selection handler...");
    var files = e.target.files;
    if(!files){
        console.log("Files selection failed. Select again");
        return;
    }//if
    try{
       var transaction = db.transaction(["docs"],"readwrite"); 
    }catch(ex){
        console.log("Exception in opening transaction, "+ex.message);
        return;
    }//catch
    transaction.onerror = function(evt){
        console.log("transaction.onerror() fired in handleFileSelection(), error code:      "+ (evt.target.error? evt.target.error: evt.target.errorCode));
    };
    transaction.onabort = function(){
        console.log("transaction.onabort() fired in handFileSelection()");
    };
    transaction.oncomplete = function(){
        console.log("transaction.oncomplete() fired in handFileSelection()");
    };

    try{
        var store = transaction.objectStore("docs");

        for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
            file = files[i];
            var request = store.put(file);
            request.onsuccess = function(){
                console.log(files.length);
                console.log(file.name+" has been successfully added in table");
            };
            request.onerror = function(evt){
                console.log("Error..."+file.name+" file not added",                                 evt.target.error.name);
            };
        }
    } catch(ex){
        console.log("Transaction and/or put() exception in adding file to     database...."+ ex.message);
        return;
    }

};

function getFiles(){
var transaction = db.transaction(["docs"],"readonly");
var cursor = transaction.objectStore("docs").openCursor();
var s ="";
cursor.onsuccess = function(e){
    var res = e.target.result;
    console.log("Cursor created");
    if(res){
        s+= "<p>"+res.value.name+"</p>";
        res.continue();
    }
    document.querySelector("#content").innerHTML = s;
};
};

function displayContent(){
var transaction = db.transaction(["docs"],"readonly");
var cursor = transaction.objectStore("docs").openCursor();
document.querySelector("#content").innerHTML = "";
cursor.onsuccess = function(e){
    console.log("Inside displayContent() cursor success...");
    var res = e.target.result;
    if(res){
        console.log(res.value.name+ " is loaded");
        readerFile(res.value);
        res.continue();
    }

};
    display="";

};

function readerFile(e){
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(e);
reader.onload = function(ex){
    var rawData = reader.result;
   display = document.querySelector("#content");
   display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML + "<h2> "+e.name+ "</h2>";
   display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML + rawData;

};

}
```

Following is my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="files/dbFile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileSelector" multiple>
    <br><br>
    <button id="displayButton">Display Content</button>
    <button id="getButton">Display Files</button>
    <pre id="content"></pre>

</body>
</html>
```

It is running successfully in all the browsers. Files are getting uploaded and stored and also getting read and displayed. But only in **Chrome** it's giving the error "Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': The object store currently does not support blob values."

Following is the output of Chrome's console, when I try uploading a file-

```
Database upgrading....
Database created
Inside file selection handler... dbFile.js:38
Transaction and/or put() exception in adding file to database....Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': The object store currently does not support blob values. dbFile.js:75
transaction.oncomplete() fired in handFileSelection()
```

Can someone please help me. Why is this happening? I did a lot of research but found nothing helpful

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error "The object store currently does not support blob values" when trying to store file in indexedDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149087/error-the-object-store-currently-does-not-support-blob-values-when-trying-to-s)

Comment: `I did a lot of research but found nothing helpful`, hard to believe as google yields plenty of results. The error message appears to be pretty clear as well, it's simply not implemented yet.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?  Chrome's support of Blobs is very recent. http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/07/Blob-support-for-IndexedDB-landed-on-Chrome-Dev

Comment: @ChileAddict I'm using Version 36.0.1985.143

Comment: I'm also not using any blob objects, so why is it showing this error?

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester I had checked that link, but even his question wasn't answered.

Comment: Have you tried in Chrome Canary? Blob should work now.

Comment: Possibly you have an error in your code that is causing confusion (and yes, Canary (version 37) is supposed to support blobs, if only your code was using them.  :-)  Have you seen these urls? http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/6/12/Issues-with-IndexedDB-and-Chrome   and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx provides examples of saving files, which is what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ChileAddict Thank you guys for helping me out. I downloaded Chrome Canary and the code is now successfully running in it. I am able to upload files now. Although I wonder, how can Chrome be the last browser to support blobs?